# Integrating Paypal Rest SDK into Rails app --

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm a fairly new developer and this is my first time integrating a rest API with an app. The goal is to implement a subscription process where a user can select from a choice of 4 subscriptions and then submit a payment through Paypal or stripe, but I'm struggling to understand how PayPal's rest API works. I've read their documentation and looked at some examples which gave me an idea of where to start. However, I had a few questions that I couldn't seem to find the answer to online:

Are subscription plans that are created through the rest API permanently associated with the account they have been created on?

If they are permanent, how can I avoid hardcoding the Plan ID? This seems like bad practice even though it is done in some of the examples.

When should I be generating new tokens? Every time they expire? Every time a user wants to subscribe to a plan?

How do I automatically execute agreements after they have been created? (I assume executing the agreement is what makes it active and begins the collection of payment).

Thanks, it would be nice to get some clarification on some of this stuff.

Comment: So it turns out the answer is don't use the paypal REST SDK, use Braintree.

Comment: Not if you want to split paypal payments, braintree can't do that.